# Avoid Runtime check of signature on APKs

Tags: signature, robotium

I want to test third party developer apps with robotium. The problem is both apk should sign with same keys. So if third party developer put constraint or some check on run time for particular signature , how can i test?

Resigning is not a solution in this case? And also the other solution i can think of multi sign. Is there any better way?

PS: I already went through related threads. I apologies if i have missed any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar happen, and the fix isn't easy. I wrote a `Robotium` program for an app that was built by a third party, but they signed it with an encrypted signature. What I had to do  was write an `Ant` script that had a `KeySigner` inside of it that made the two signatures match. Even with that though, I still have 4 things I have to do in order to launch the test app.

I guess the short answer is: No, unless you have the signature or can create a new one, your a out of luck.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give us some more details about what you did and how? :)

Comment: What type of details do you want?

Comment: How do create matching signatures and how do you start the instrumentation with that matching signature?

Comment: You have to have the original key signature, and the we used an ANT build to sign the app.